# Confusion in getting Parent from JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON document stored in a text file

```
{
    "attributes": {"attr0":"value0"},
    "children" : {
        "ProductA" : {
            "attributes": {"attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2"}, 
            "children" : {
                "ProductC":{
                    "attributes": {"attr3":"value3", "attr4":"value4"}, 
                    "children" : {}, 
                    "referencedChildren" : {}
                }
            }, 
            "referencedChildren" : {}
        }, 
        "ProductB" : {
            "attributes": {"attr5":"value5", "attr6":"value6"}, 
            "children" : {}, 
            "referencedChildren" : {}
        }
    },
    "referencedChildren" : {}
}
```

I have written this code in C# using NewtonSoft JSon.NET Library

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\foo.txt");
JToken token = JToken.Parse(content);
JToken p2 = token["children"]["ProductA"]["children"]["ProductC"];
```

This works and I get the node for `p2`.

However if I want the node for `ParentA` from the `p2` node. I have to say

```
JToken p1 = p2.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
Console.WriteLine(((JProperty)p1).Name);
```

The code above prints `"ProductA"`. But the the confusing part is that why do I have to call parent 5 times.

When I look at my document, I can see that `"children"` is the parent of `"ProductC"` and then `"ProductA"` is the parent of children. Therefore 2 calls to `Parent` should have got me `ParentA`.

Why do I need 5 calls?

Comment: I suggest you look at what you've got at each level of "parent". I don't know the answer offhand, but that would be my next diagnostic step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hierarchy you're traversing is how Json.net structures the objects, it is not representative of the json string itself.

Relative to the `ProductA` object (well, one up), this is how you get down to `ProductC`:

```
JProperty: "ProductA"
 -> JObject (ProductA object)
     -> JProperty: "children"
         -> JObject (children object)
             -> JProperty: "ProductC"
                 -> JObject (ProductC object)  *you are here
```

So if you look at it this way, you should see that you are actually accessing the `JProperty` "ProductA" (5 parents up), not the object itself.  As you might have noticed, `JObject`s do not have a name, you're getting the name of the `JProperty`.

I can't tell you how exactly you can access it as it is described in the json string, it doesn't appear to be an option.  But you could of course write some helper methods to get them for you.

Here's one implementation to get the parent object.  I don't know what other JTokens we'd encounter that we'd want to skip, but this is a start.  Just pass in the token you want to get the parent of.  Pass in an optional parent number to indicate which parent you want.

```
JToken GetParent(JToken token, int parent = 0)
{
    if (token == null)
        return null;
    if (parent < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Must be positive");

    var skipTokens = new[]
    {
        typeof(JProperty),
    };
    return token.Ancestors()
        .Where(a => skipTokens.All(t => !t.IsInstanceOfType(a)))
        .Skip(parent)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```