# Tricky business of discovering parent node in JSON.Net

Tags: json, json.net

this is further to my question here

[JSON.NET - Confusion in getting Parent from JToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532567/json-net-confusion-in-getting-parent-from-jtoken)

I am still having problems in understanding how to discover the parent in JSON.NET

So Now I have this JSON Document

```
{
    "attributes": {"attr0":"value0"},
    "children" : {
        "ProductA" : {
            "attributes": {"attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2"}, 
            "children" : {
                "ProductC":{
                    "attributes": {"attr3":"value3", "attr4":"value4"}, 
                    "children" : {
                        "ProductD":{
                            "attributes": {"attr7":"value7", "attr8":"value8"}, 
                            "children" : {
                                "ProductE":{
                                    "attributes": {"attr9":"value9", "attr10":"value10"}, 
                                    "children" : {}, 
                                    "referencedChildren" : {}
                                }
                            }, 
                            "referencedChildren" : {}
                        }
                    }, 
                    "referencedChildren" : {}
                }
            }, 
            "referencedChildren" : {}
        }, 
        "ProductB" : {
            "attributes": {"attr5":"value5", "attr6":"value6"}, 
            "children" : {}, 
            "referencedChildren" : {}
        }
    },
    "referencedChildren" : {}
}
```

Based on this I have written this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace JSonTest {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string content = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\foo.txt");
      JObject token = JObject.Parse(content);
      JToken p2 = token["children"]["ProductA"]["children"]["ProductC"]["children"]["ProductD"]["children"]["ProductE"];
      JToken parent = p2;
      do {
        parent = GetParentModule(parent);
        Console.WriteLine(((JProperty)parent).Name);
      } while (parent != null);
    }

    private static JToken GetParentModule(JToken token) {
      JToken retVal = token;
      int i = 5;
      while (i > 0) {
        retVal = retVal.Parent;
        if (retVal == null) {
          break;
        } else {
          --i;
        }
      }
      return retVal;
    }
  }    
}
```

When I run this code, the first call to GetParentModule return "ParentD"... but the second call does not return "ParentC"

My objective here is that when I call GetParentModule on ProductE it returns ProductD and when I call GetParentModule on ProductD it returns ProductC and when I call GetParentModule on ParentC it returns ProductA.

In my previous thread I found that 5 calls to Parent, returned me the parent correctly. but in subsequent calls I see that "4" calls to Parent returns the "ProductC".

Can you please explain what is going on and how can walk up the parent hierarchy successfully?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are confused because of two factors working against you in concert:

1. The actual in-memory hierarchy used by Json.Net does not match your mental model of the JSON.
2. The syntax `token["property"]` simplifies downward traversal of the JSON by abstracting away the actual structure to better fit your mental model.  But, there is no such convenience for navigating upward, so you are exposed to all the extra layers.

Let's take a simplified example of your JSON and explore what's going on in a little more detail.  Say we have this JSON:

```
{
    "children": {
        "ProductA": {
            "children": {
                "ProductC": {
                    "attribute": "some stuff"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your mental model you have this:

- a top-level object (with no name), which contains

  - an object named "children", which contains

    - an object named "ProductA", which contains

      - an object named "children", which contains

        - an object named "ProductC", which contains

          - an attribute with a value of "some stuff".

But the Json.Net object model works like this:

- A `JObject` is a collection of `JProperty` objects.
- A `JProperty` is a name-value pair, where the name is string and the value is either a `JObject`, `JValue` or `JArray`.
- The children of a `JObject` are its `JProperties`.
- The child of a `JProperty` is its value.

So the actual in-memory representation of the JSON is:

- a top-level JObject, which contains

  - a JProperty named "children" which contains

    - a JObject, which contains

      - a JProperty named "ProductA", which contains

        - a JObject, which contains

          - a JProperty named "children", which contains

            - a JObject, which contains

              - a JProperty named "ProductC", which contains

                - a JObject, which contains

                  - a JProperty named "attribute", which contains

                    - a JValue with a string value of "some stuff".

So you can see that what you think of as a single named object is actually an unnamed JObject wrapped inside named JProperty.  And this serves to make the object hierarchy twice as deep as you would expect.

When you do something like this:

```
JObject productA = (JObject)top["children"]["ProductA"];
```

these extra layers are hidden from you.  It looks just as if each object (or property) is nested directly in the one above it.  But don't be fooled.  Under the covers, this indexer syntax is really just a shortcut for this equivalent code:

```
JObject productA = (JObject)top.Children<JProperty>()
                               .First(prop => prop.Name == "children")
                               .Value
                               .Children<JProperty>()
                               .First(prop => prop.Name == "ProductA")
                               .Value;
```

Hopefully by now it should be clear what is going on, and we can get back to your real question, which is how to go up the chain and get the desired result.  For example, say we have a reference to product C and we want to get product A (or more exactly, we have a reference to the JObject that is the value of the JProperty whose name is "ProductC", and we want to go up the chain to get the value of the JProperty whose name is "ProductA").  How can we do that?

Well, again, if you look at the actual Json.Net structure, you can see a pattern to it.  Each JObject that you've identified as a "product" is inside a JProperty with an "interesting" name that is not "children".  And if that product has a "parent product", it will have an ancestor JProperty whose name *is* "children".  And the parent of that JProperty is the one you want.

So in other words, all you need to do is walk upward until you find the first JProperty whose name is "children", then take the parent of that JProperty, and that should be the JObject you are looking for.

In code:

```
private static JToken GetParentModule(JToken token)
{
    while (token != null && 
          (token.Type != JTokenType.Property ||
          ((JProperty)token).Name != "children"))
    {
        token = token.Parent;
    }
    return (token != null ? token.Parent : null);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code as per your suggestion and ran it against the json document I have published above. it failed and did not return productD as the parent of ProductE.

Comment: This is working for me `private static JToken GetParentModule(JToken token) {
      JToken retVal = null;
      while (token != null) {
        token = token.Parent;
        if (token != null && token.Parent != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)token.Parent).Name != "children") {
          retVal = token.Parent;
          break;
        }
      }
      return retVal;
    }
` Do you think this is correct?

Comment: The difference between your version and mine is that yours returns the JProperty that has the product JObject, while mine returns the JObject which is the value of that JProperty.  So, to use my version you'd have to change your calling code to account for this.  That is probably why it failed for you.  Your version is probably better for your purposes anyway because you have the JProperty in hand, so you can get the product name from the JProperty `Name` and the product data from the JProperty `Value`.  So, yeah, looks good.  I'd say go with it.