# C# JSON File to Datatable and Accessing Child Columns

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

The code listed below reads an Atlassian HipChat JSON file and stuffs the data into a data table.  However, I am having an issue getting the name and user_id in my SaveToExcel method as these appear to be child columns with the from column being the parent.  I can see the values when I inspect the item array when stepping through the code.  How can access these values?

**Sample JSON**

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2015-12-30T14:10:47+0000",
      "from":{  
         "name":"Test user",
         "user_id":437410
  },
  "message":"how did everyone enjoy their rides w\/ their new friends this morning?"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-12-30T14:12:47+0000",
      "from":{  
         "name":"Test User 2",
         "user_id":2535653
  },
  "message":"i didnt have to ride with strangers this morning lol "
   }]
```

**C# Code**

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string parseDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseDirectory"];
        string archiveDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveDirectory"];
        string parseSearchPattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseSearchPattern"];

        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(parseDirectory,parseSearchPattern))
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

            object obj = JArray.Parse(json);
            var messageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(obj.ToString());
            DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(messageList);

            SaveToExcel(dt, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
            MoveTo(fi, parseDirectory, archiveDirectory);
        }
    }

    static void SaveToExcel(DataTable dt, string fileName)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string date = dt.Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
            string message = dt.Rows[0]["message"].ToString();
            string file = dt.Rows[0]["file"].ToString();
            string from = dt.Rows[0]["from"].ToString();

        }         
    }

    private static void MoveTo(FileInfo fi, string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
    {
        string targetFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", targetDirectory, fi.FullName.Replace(sourceDirectory, ""));
        FileInfo targetFile = new FileInfo(targetFilename);
        try
        {
            if (!targetFile.Directory.Exists)
            {
                targetFile.Directory.Create();
            }

            fi.MoveTo(targetFilename);
        }
        catch (Exception exc2)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Error moving {0} to {1}: {2}\n{3}", fi.FullName, targetFilename, exc2.Message, exc2.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public class From
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class File
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public From from { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public File file { get; set; }
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the JSON that is causing problems?

Comment: I have added a sample of the JSON.  When looking at this a little more, I see where the entire object of the FROM class is in the data table, I just don't know how to access the name and user_id.

Comment: What are you trying to write, a CSV file?  If so, you might try preprocessing the JSON by flattening it using the method `PromoteNamedPropertiesToParents()` from [Flattening out a JToken](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27715597/3744182).

Comment: The requirement is to dump the HipChat history to an Excel spreadsheet, for our security team to audit.  I was able to access the property directly by using ((JSON_Reader.Program.From)(dr.ItemArray[1])).name.ToString().  However, I like the idea of flattening out the JToken with the PromoteNamedPropertiesToParents() method.  Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following expression to the SaveToExcel method to get the name and user id values from my data table

```
string name = ((JSON_Reader.Program.From)(dr.ItemArray[1])).name.ToString();
string userId = ((JSON_Reader.Program.From)(dr.ItemArray[1])).user_id.ToString();
```

C# Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string parseDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseDirectory"];
    string archiveDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveDirectory"];
    string parseSearchPattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseSearchPattern"];

    foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(parseDirectory,parseSearchPattern))
    {
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

        object obj = JArray.Parse(json);
        var messageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(obj.ToString());
        DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(messageList);

        SaveToExcel(dt, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
        MoveTo(fi, parseDirectory, archiveDirectory);
    }
}

static void SaveToExcel(DataTable dt, string fileName)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        string date = dt.Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
        string message = dt.Rows[0]["message"].ToString();
        string file = dt.Rows[0]["file"].ToString();
        string from = dt.Rows[0]["from"].ToString();
        string name = ((JSON_Reader.Program.From)(dr.ItemArray[1])).name.ToString();
        string userId = ((JSON_Reader.Program.From)(dr.ItemArray[1])).user_id.ToString();

    }         
}

private static void MoveTo(FileInfo fi, string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
{
    string targetFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", targetDirectory, fi.FullName.Replace(sourceDirectory, ""));
    FileInfo targetFile = new FileInfo(targetFilename);
    try
    {
        if (!targetFile.Directory.Exists)
        {
            targetFile.Directory.Create();
        }

        fi.MoveTo(targetFilename);
    }
    catch (Exception exc2)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("Error moving {0} to {1}: {2}\n{3}", fi.FullName, targetFilename, exc2.Message, exc2.StackTrace);
    }
}

public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public File file { get; set; }
}

public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
       TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;

}
}
```